# GetElementResult() null iText 7

Tags: c#, itext7

I am converting html to pdf and trying to get the  tag coordinates to be able to locate the example text.

```
<html>

  <body>

     <p><font><strong>example text</strong></font></p>

  </body>

</html>
```

```
private class CustomSpanTagWorker : SpanTagWorker
{
    public CustoSpanTagWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) : base(element, context)
    {
    }
    
    public override void ProcessEnd(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context)
    {
        base.ProcessEnd(element, context);

        IPropertyContainer elementResult = GetElementResult();
        
    }

}
```

```
public class CustomTagWorker : DefaultTagWorkerFactory
{
    public override ITagWorker GetCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context)
    {     
      
            if (tag.Name().Equals(TagConstants.STRONG, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                
                return new CustoSpanTagWorker(tag, context);
                
            }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

but I get a GetElementResult () null, when I iterate the element. Please help me to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `<span>` HTML element may be mapped to multiple layout elements, so you should use `SpanTagWorker#getAllElements` instead of `SpanTagWorker#getElementResult`